# Can a datetime.date object without the day be created in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to enter a date in Python but sometimes I don't know the exact day or month. So I would like to record only the year. I would like to do something like:

```
datetime.date(year=1940, month="0 or None", day="0 or None")
```

Is there a code for doing this? Or if not, how would you manage to deal with this problem?

Comment: Please do not use both python 2 and 3 tags. If the question in't version-specific, just use the python tag.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, you can't pass `0` because there is no month `0` so you'll get `ValueError: month must be in 1..12`, you cannot skip the month or the day as both are required.

If you do not know the exact year or month, just pass in 1 for the month and day and then keep only the year part.

```
>>> d = datetime.date(year=1940, month=1, day=1)
>>> d
datetime.date(1940, 1, 1)
>>> d.year
1940
>>> d = datetime.date(year=1940, month=1, day=1).year
>>> d
1940
```

The second statement is a shorthand for the first.

However, if you want to just store the year, you don't need a datetime object. You can store the integer value separately. A date object implies month and day.

Answer (score 9):

Pandas has Period class where you don't have to supply day if you don't know that:

```
import pandas as pd

pp = pd.Period('2013-12', 'M')
print pp
print pp + 1
print pp - 1
print (pp + 1).year, (pp + 1).month
```

Output:

```
2013-12
2014-01
2013-11
2014 1
```